# Assign Field Value in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, formula

is there a way to assign a value to a field in Visualforce by using a formula calculated in the Mark Up? Or is this best handled with an Apex Controller?
Below is a simple example. I would like to have the final value assigned to a number field rather than simply displayed on the page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Relationship_Owner__c">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Test Health Check Data">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Relationship_Owner__c.List_Growth_Score__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Relationship_Owner__c.List_Size_Score__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Relationship_Owner__c.Unsubscribe_Score__c}"/>
            <p>
                The total score is:  {! Relationship_Owner__c.List_Growth_Score__c + Relationship_Owner__c.List_Size_Score__c + Relationship_Owner__c.Unsubscribe_Score__c}
            </p>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: yes, handle it in apex extension (controller)

Comment: Yes, it's better to handle it in the controller. Either assign the result to the field or create a property.

Comment: Create a formula field if you are also considering to use this value somewhere else - e.g. reports.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `Total_Score__c` field on Relationship_Owner__c object to store total score, create the followin  extension

```
public class RelationshipOwnerExtension {

    private Relationship_Owner__c record;

    public RelationshipOwnerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        initStandardController(stdController);
        populateFields();
    }

    private void initStandardController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) stdController.addFields(new List<String> {'Total_Score__c'});
        record = (Relationship_Owner__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public void populateFields(){
        record.Total_Score__c = record.List_Growth_Score__c + record.List_Size_Score__c + record.Unsubscribe_Score__c;
    }
}
```